# Loading Simplepie feed url from database

Tags: php, simplepie

I am using simplepie 1.5 and fetching multiple feed  urls

```
$feed->set_feed_url(array('x','y','z'));
```

How can I load the feed URLs from my database table?

Attaching the code used.

```
$results = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM source_list");

    $source;
    $source_data;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        foreach($row as $key => $value ) {
            if($key==='source_name'){
                $source=$value;
            }

        }
         $source_data= $source_data."'".$source."'".',';     
    }
$feed = new SimplePie();

  $source_data= substr($source_data, 0, -1);

   echo($source_data);
   $url=array($source_data);
   $feed->set_feed_url($url);
```

Comment: Welcome, we'd need to know what database you are using, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle ...? And I'm sure there are tons of tutorials/howtos out there on the web on how to fetch data from a database.

Comment: @kerbholz This is the code I am using. Can you please help to solve the error

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$results = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM source_list");

$feedurls = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
  array_push($feedurls, $row['source_name']);
}

// var_dump($feedurls);

$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url($feedurls);
```

Like in your first code example we're setting an array of URLs to fetch (`$feedurls`). You can uncomment `var_dump($feedurls);` to check if the array contains the desired URLs from your database.